# How can i check the Terrain bounds to avoid the characters from walking out and falling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the top

```
public GameObject[] waypoints;
public Transform target;
public float moveSpeed = 1f;
public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
Transform myTransform;

public float walkSpeed = 10f;
public ThirdPersonCharacter[] thirdPersonCharacter;

Vector3 boundLower;
Vector3 boundUpper;
public Terrain terrain;
```

Awake and Start:

```
void Awake()
{
    myTransform = transform;
}

void Start()
{
    GameObject tpc1 = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
    thirdPersonCharacter[0] = tpc1.GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();
    GameObject tpc2 = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController (1)");
    thirdPersonCharacter[1] = tpc2.GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();

    waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObject");

    boundLower = terrain.transform.position - terrain.terrainData.size / 2;
    boundUpper = terrain.transform.position + terrain.terrainData.size / 2;
}
```

The Update:

```
void Update()
{
    thirdPersonCharacter[0].m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = walkSpeed;
    thirdPersonCharacter[1].m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = walkSpeed;
    WayPoints();
    CheckBounds();
}
```

The WayPoints:

```
int index = 0;

private void WayPoints()
{
    if (index == waypoints.Length)
        index = 0;

    target = waypoints[index].transform;
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);

    myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,
          Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position),
          rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (distance < 2f)
        index++;
}
```

And the CheckBounds:

```
private Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;

void CheckBounds()
{
    foreach (var child in thirdPersonCharacter)
    {
        var pos = child.transform.position;
        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, boundLower.x, boundUpper.x);
        pos.z = Mathf.Clamp(pos.z, boundLower.z, boundUpper.z);
        if (pos.x == boundLower.x || pos.x == boundUpper.x) direction.x = -direction.x;
        if (pos.z == boundLower.z || pos.z == boundUpper.z) direction.z = -direction.z;
        child.transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Once i added the CheckBounds function and call it from the Update function the characters are walking on place. Not moving. Without the checkBounds they are walking fine between the waypoints. What i want to do is that if the character walked to the terrain edge(bound) just make him turn/rotate back or stop at place.

I must say that the characters(ThirdPersonController) are moving out of the Terrain bounds and falling only if i change the walking speed to 30 for example or more. But in any case i would like to know how to use the CheckBounds for other situations for example if a player is just walking to the Terrain bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways how to make a `Boundary` for a game. One example for all is in 1st and 2nd tutorial on Unity web:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/setting-play-area?playlist=17141

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/boundary?playlist=17147

You can do it 3 ways:

- Create "`Boundary`" object around the map, create `Trigger` and once somebody hit the trigger, push him back/stop him/don't allow him pass
- Create "`Boundary`" object which fill whole map. Create `Trigger` on the `OnExit` method and once some object will try to leave, stop him/push back/don't allow him to pass
- Stick to the programming and some "map" concept where You know the location of `Boundaries`. In such case You have to check the position and whenever the objects leaves behind the boundary, You have to stop him - this has to happen every update frame, not just on Triggers

Based on the size of the map and complexity of the game, I would pick one of the topper answers. Once the game get complicated You have to create own engine in an engine to handle map control & other things. But first: **Step by step.**

This code should work (once somebody cross the border, set to the border location + minimal step into center of map):

```
var pos = child.transform.position;
float step = 1; //adjust to fit scale/size of step

if (pos.x <= boundLower.x) pos.x = boundLower.x + step;
if (pos.x >= boundUpper.x) pos.x = boundUpper.x - step;
if (pos.z <= boundLower.z) pos.z = boundLower.z + step;
if (pos.z >= boundUpper.z) pos.z = boundUpper.z - step;

child.transform.position = pos;
```

Comment: I tried the code in your solution. I added the code to a method to the CheckBounds instead the code i used before. And calling CheckBounds from the Update function. But when running the game the characters both ThirdPersonController and ThirdPersonController (1) are walking on place. That's whay in my code i'm using the foreach: foreach (var child in thirdPersonCharacter) i'm also not using the WayPoints to let the characters to get to the terrain bounds. I think the line  child.transform.position = pos; make them walk on place not moving. If i remove this line they will walk forward but fall.

Comment: There might be several issues. One of them might be that You are using wrong axis. Is it surely `X` and `Z` ? Can't it be `Y`? You might wanna use just 1st and 2nd line, (for `X axis`) and test it he moves in any direction.

Comment: Also You should probably call the `CheckBound()` from the GameObject (each `Controller`) for itself only and they should check if their position is out of bounds. This way You are sticking to the object oriented principle - `OOP`, more then having one object (class) which controls everything.